# When I get images from the drive Api, they take up a lot of memory

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

The images come from the drive api, but they take up a lot (950MB 18 photos), and in the original each takes up 1.5 MB

[image: memory_photo]

```
private let service: GTLRDriveService

init(service: GTLRDriveService) {
    self.service = service
}
  
func download(_ fileItem: GTLRDrive_File, onCompleted: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> ()) {
    guard let fileID = fileItem.identifier else {
        return onCompleted(nil, nil)
    }
    print(fileItem.json)
    self.service.executeQuery(GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet.queryForMedia(withFileId: fileID)) { (ticket, file, error) in
        if let error = error {
            return onCompleted(nil, error)
        }

        guard let data = (file as? GTLRDataObject)?.data else {
            return onCompleted(nil, nil)
        }
        print(data)
        onCompleted(data, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: why do 18 images take up 1 gigabyte of memory, when in fact it should be no more than 20mb

Comment: That's memory usage is your app, not necessarily the image data.  Have you checked immediately before and after making the API call?   And after repeating the API call.  Have you looked at the size fo the data objects being returned?  Is the data provided raw data and the disk compressed?  How are you processing/storing the data - does that result in temporary/multiple copies?  There's not enough background here to give an definitive answer (unless there's a known library bug).

Comment: @flanker Each object occupies 3 million bytes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.